# Find the first two elements that are out of order and swap them

Tags: python

hoping someone can help me with my code. I'm new to python and software development. I'm trying to find the first two elements that are out of order and swap them.

```
arr = [5, 22, 29, 39, 19, 51, 78, 96, 84]
i = 0
while (i < arr.len() - 1) and (arr[i] < arr[i+1]):
  i += i
print(i)
  arr[i] = arr[i+1]
  arr[i+1] = arr[i]
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the code itself as well-formatted text.

Comment: Can you post directly post your code directly in the description, and post your error message ? Firstly, it seems to be a python syntax error, you may need to read the Python's documentation.

Comment: There are a lot of issues with the code you're provided: the indentation is wrong (it matters in python!), and when you try to swap the values, you'll find you'll lose the original value, you'll need a temporary or some kind of swap function.

Comment: Sorry everyone I've never posted on here before so I didnt know. I'll post the code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arr = [1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 6]    
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
        arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
        break
print(arr)
```